# How to generate exponential distributions from finite random variables?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $ {\textstyle \{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n},\ldots \}}$ be a sequence random variables

For the summation of those random variable:

$ {\displaystyle {\bar {X}}_{n}\equiv {\frac {X_{1}+\cdots +X_{n}}{n}}}$

We know if each $X_i$ is a random variable for an independent simple binominal random walk, then ${\bar {X}}_{n}$ follow a normal distribution.

Question: What kind of simple sequences of random variables (which takes finite values) can naturally lead to an exponential distribution in the limit (like binormal random walks do for normal distributions) ?

Comment: I would guess that no _simple_ sequence of random variables would converge to an exponential distribution in the limit.  If we interpret "simple" to mean at least "independent and finite variance," then the central limit theorem will take over and we'll have convergence to a normal distribution. I don't think you could build dependency into the sequence and still have it called "simple," but I suppose one might still consider infinite variance random variables to be simple. But in that case, $\bar X_n$ would also have infinite variance, and hence wouldn't be exponentially distributed.

Comment: No, $\overline{X}_n$ is not normal, it is just approximately normal.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @user6247850

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you want is something like this.  Let $X_n$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $\mu/n$ (i.e. the waiting time for the first success in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with probability of success $\mu/n$ in each).  Then the distribution of $X_n/n$ converges to an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that is somewhat similar to the sum of a large class of random variables converging to a normal distribution is that the minimum of certain random variables often converges to an exponential distribution.

Specifically, if $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ are iid non-negative random variables with density $f$ such that $f(0) = \lambda$, then
$$
n \min\{X_1, \dotsc, X_n\}
$$
converges in distribution to an $\mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$ distribution.

(For a discussion of this result, see this post: [Convergence in distribution of minimum of IID random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043257/convergence-in-distribution-of-minimum-of-iid-random-variables))